# Why does depends_on argument is not activated

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have one folder where I keep the `main.tf` and `variables.tf` and I got stucked when trying to create a load balancer for my 2 instances:

```
resource "aws_instance" "wordpress-app-eu-west-2a" {
  ami = var.bastion-ami
  instance_type = var.bastion-instance-type
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public-eu-west-2a.id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.bastion.id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  key_name = "wordpress-key"
  user_data = file("wordpressapp.sh")
  tags = {
    Name = "Wordpress-APP-2a"
  }
}
```

The above code is the same for the 2nd instance `wordpress-app-eu-west-2a`

I have created the resource `"aws_lb"` , `resource "aws_lb_target_group"` , `resource "aws_lb_listener"` but I get an error when configuring the `resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment"`

```
 aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2a.id will be known only after apply
 aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2b.id will be known only after apply
```

Inappropriate value for attribute "target_id": string required.`

Here is the configuration for the `"aws_lb_target_group_attachment"`:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "wordpress" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.wordpress.arn
  target_id = [aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2b.id, aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2a.id]
  port = 80

  depends_on = [aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2b, aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2a]
}
```

I tried to google why this behaviour might happen but I couldn't find a reason to understand why the `depends_on` is not working as it should.

---

Initial error message:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

on main.tf line 393, in resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "wordpress":

393:   target_id = [aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2b.id, aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2a.id]

aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2a.id will be known only after apply
aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2b.id will be known only after apply

Inappropriate value for attribute "target_id": string required.
```

Then I found this article - https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/aws-target-group-attachment-target-id-error/37558

The new code of the `aws_lb_target_group_attachment` looks like this:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "wordpress" {

  for_each = toset([aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2b.id, aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2a.id])
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.wordpress.arn
  target_id = each.key
  port = 80

  depends_on = [
   aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2b,
   aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2a
 ]
}
```

But when doing a `terraform plan` I get another error regarding `for_each` :

```
Error: Invalid for_each argument

on main.tf line 391, in resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "wordpress":
  391:   for_each = toset([aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2b.id, aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2a.id])

aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2a.id is a string, known only after apply
aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2b.id is a string, known only after apply

The "for_each" set includes values derived from resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, and so Terraform cannot determine the full set of keys that will identify the instances of this resource.

When working with unknown values in for_each, it's better to use a map value where the keys are defined statically in your configuration and where only the values contain apply-time results.

Alternatively, you could use the -target planning option to first apply only the resources that the for_each value depends on, and then apply a second time to fully converge.
```

Comment: The `depends_on` argument you showed here is entirely redundant: Terraform can already see those same dependencies in the definition of the `target_id` argument. Therefore I think `depends_on` is not relevant to your problem. Please edit your question to include the entire output of Terraform _exactly as Terraform printed it_ (without editing out any parts) so that hopefully those reading the question can understand what is causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `aws_lb_target_group_attachment` instance represents an association between exactly one target group and exactly one "target" (e.g. EC2 instance).

Therefore to add more than one EC2 instance to the same target group requires one instance of `aws_lb_target_group_attachment` for each of the EC2 instances.

It is possible to achieve that using `for_each`, but `for_each` requires each of the instances to have a unique key decided in your configuration which you provide as the keys of the map value assigned to `for_each`. Your EC2 instances are not already naturally in a map, so a good first step is to construct that map as a [local value](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/locals):

```
local {
  wordpress_instance_ids = tomap({
    "eu-west-2a" = aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2a.id
    "eu-west-2b" = aws_instance.wordpress-app-eu-west-2b.id
  })
}
```

With that declaration, `local.wordpress_instance_ids` is a map from availability zone to EC2 instance ID. Crucially, there is one entry in this map per EC2 instance and so this map is now ready to use with resource `for_each` to declare multiple target group attachments:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "wordpress" {
  for_each = local.wordpress_instance_ids

  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.wordpress.arn
  target_id        = each.value
  port             = 80
}
```

Because the keys of `local.wordpress_instance_ids` are the availability zones, this declares two target group attachment instances with the following addresses:

- `aws_lb_target_group_attachment.wordpress["eu-west-2a"]`
- `aws_lb_target_group_attachment.wordpress["eu-west-2b"]`

The resource configuration uses `each.value` to refer to the value of each element of the map, which in this case means the EC2 instance ID for each availability zone.